# How to pull a string of numbers out of a table that are placed randomly

Tags: sql, db2

I'm attempting to isolate eight digits from a cell that contains other numbers as well as text and no rhyme or reason to where it is placed. An example return would look something like this:

```
will deliver 11/07 in USA at 12:30 with conf# 12345678
```

I need the conf# only, but it could be at the end, beginning, middle of the string and I don't know how to isolate it.  I'm working in DB2 so I can't use functions such as PATINDEX or CHARINDEX, so what are my other option for pulling out only "12345678" regardless of where it is located?

Comment: While this is possible to do entirely through SQL using a variety of functions (https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0011043.html) and loops, I would recommend not going that route. What you are asking is a fairly complicated logic for SQL... I would suggest using a simple SQL query to pull the entire field and then using another language like Java or C# to extract the characters you need.

Comment: I wish that were an option, but unfortunately, I'm limited to isolating this information within the SQL query only at this point.

Comment: What DB2 version and platform?

Answer (score 0):

While DB2 doesn't have PATINDEX or CHARINDEX, it does have [LOCATE](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/api/content/nl/en-us/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000820.html).

Answer (score 0):

If your DB2 version supportx pureXML, you can use the regular expression support in XQuery, something like:

```
select xmlcast(
 xmlquery(
   ' if (fn:matches( $YOURCOLUMN, "(^|.*[^\d])(\d{8})([^\d].*$|$)")) then fn:replace( $YOURCOLUMN,"(^|.*[^\d])(\d{8})([^\d].*$|$)","$2") else "" '
 )
 as varchar(20)
)
from YOURTABLE
```

This assumes that 8-digit sequence appears only once in the column. You may need to tweak the regex to support some border cases.

Comment: I have never used XQuery before and attempted to use the above expression and returned an error as it couldn't define my column name.  It's possible I manipulated expression incorrectly, but it appears to at least be attempting to process the information.  I got the following error:  ERROR [10506] [IBM][DB2] SQL16005N  An XQuery expression references an element name, attribute name, type name, function name, namespace prefix, or variable name "COLUMN_NAME" that is not defined within the static context. Error QName=err:XPST0008.

Comment: Sorry, I can't see your statement clearly from here, and my crystal ball is at the shop for repairs.