# How to search for values that are a number value in the where clause ?

Tags: sql, db2

I have these values

```
'12345/1'
'23456/1'
'34567/1'
```

But occasionally these are submitted

```
'a1234/1'
```

How can I explicitly return results where the values are all numbers?
I currently am doing this

```
SELECT SID FROM TRACE WHERE SID LIKE '_____%'
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: not sure if this will work in db2 but in mssql you can use something like `WHERE SID NOT LIKE '%[A-Z]%'`

Comment: Could any character be a letter, or just the first one as in your example?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Test for numeric value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8565275/test-for-numeric-value)

Comment: See also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8565275/test-for-numeric-value/8566231#8566231), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23489752/determine-if-zip-code-contains-numbers-only/23489951#23489951) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33740890/how-to-pull-a-string-of-numbers-out-of-a-table-that-are-placed-randomly)

Answer (score 0):

DB2 doesn't support regular expressions.  But, you can do what you want using `translate()`:

```
where translate(sid, '/', '/0123456789') = '/'
```

This removes all digits from the string . . . and then checks if you are just left with a single slash.

Comment: No, this replaces the zero with a slash and removes all other characters. Should be `'/0123456789'` instead. But I don't think DB2 treats `''` as `NULL` and the syntax is different from Oracle, switches *to* and *from*, so this should work: `translate(sid, '', '0123456789')`
.